# Arraylist indexOf returns -1

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, arraylist

I have one arraylist named gatherSplit which gets elements from a string named splitMeToDelete which contains the following:

```
splitMeToDelete = "Salary, Personal Savings, Pensions, Annuities, Social Security"
```

The string is split like this into ArrayList:

```
ArrayList gatherSplit = new ArrayList(splitMeToDelete.Split(new char[] { ',' }));
```

When I give the following line of code, I should be getting IndexOf as 3 instad I get error.

```
gatherSplit.RemoveAt(gatherSplit.IndexOf("Annuities"));
```

Error I get is:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

I do not understand why is this happening.

Answer (score 8):

Your call to `IndexOf` is returning -1, because the item in the array contains " Annuities" (leading space).  Try `Trim` on each item to remove the space:

```
ArrayList gatherSplit = new ArrayList(
    splitMeToDelete.Split(new char[] { ',' }).Select(item => item.Trim()).ToArray()
);
```

(Or maybe easier, just split on `", ".ToCharArray()`.)

Comment: Thanks.. however it gives another error as Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'System.Collections.ICollection' C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Dropbox\PE\PE\AddItems.cs 121 55 PE

Comment: @Anand sorry, see my update-- should be fixed now.  I didn't realize that `ArrayList` won't take an `IEnumerable` in its constructor (have to convert it to an array first).

Comment: Thank you so much... I could notice the space. It worked for me.

Comment: Also, consider using strong-typed generic List<string> since it gives you type-safety.

Comment: @AlirezaMaddah right, it seems like there's no need for `ArrayList` in this case, since all the items are the same type.

Comment: Better option would be, `splitMeToDelete.Split(new [] {',' ' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what dbaseman has pointed out, you can just use `Remove` for this.

```
gatherSplit.Remove(" Annuities"); //Note the space if you don't do the trim that dbaseman suggests.
```

Also you could set a break point in your code on the line that causes the problem and hover over "gatherSplit" to see what value it has, press the plus to inspect inside the object and you will see the extra spaces.

Clicking where the red circle is in the image is how to set a breakpoint.

[image: Debugging to see the problem]

Comment: Thank you so much... I could notice the space.

Comment: Both the tricks worked for me - yours and dbaseman. I was struggling for 4 hours

Answer (score 0):

Please check the spaces between each item

[image]

Instead of above string try using,

```
string splitMeToDelete = "Salary,Personal Savings,Pensions,Annuities,Social Security";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this below line. It is splitting with the space. It is not visible in the snap shot but click on 'Text Visualizer' to see, it contains space.

```
ArrayList gatherSplit = new ArrayList(splitMeToDelete.Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```